# Lightning flow auto navigate to subsequent flow elements when page is refreshed

Tags: visual-workflow, admin, screen-flow, lightning-flow-builder

I have a lightning flow with multiple screen elements, apex actions, and record update elements. We are creating a task record after the flow is finished (When the **Finish** button is pressed on the last screen element), Screenshot below.
[image]
But when we are on the last screen element (where the **Finish** button is displayed) and perform page refresh, then flow assumes the **Finish** button is pressed and it auto navigates to the subsequent actions. is this an expected behavior or some sort of issue with the lightning flow?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, There was unknown apex automation kicked in when I partially updated the case record which made the flow conditions act accordingly.